# how to convert f3d format to zf3d format with Flare3D?

Tags: flare3d

I have about 10 .f3d models and need to convert to zf3d. Any idea if there is simple solution for this ?

Many thanks.

Eugene

Answer (score 0):

F3D format is no longer supported (a new and optimized F3D version is now in developing and will be ready for a future Flare3D version).
If you want to use old F3D models you can convert them using Flare3D IDE. 
Drag and drop the old model into the IDE, and saving it you will get a ZF3D instead the original F3D.